# How to convert an IntPtr to byte array in c#?

Tags: .net

I need to send data from the first part of the project, thats written in C#, to the second one, written in C++. For that i need to understand how convert an byte array to IntPtr.

Comment: Just declare the parameter as byte[] in the [DllImport] declaration.  The pinvoke marshaller takes care of pinning the array and passing a pointer to the first element of the array so the native code can safely access the data.

Comment: so, in the title you want to convert from IntPtr to byte array, but in the question from byte array to IntPtr? or do you actually need an IntPtr from the bytearray to reference it in the C++ part?

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at:
[Marshal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal?view=netcore-3.1)
and
[Stackalloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/stackalloc)

I think there is no native "method", but this should work:

```
    public unsafe static byte[] IntPtrToArray(IntPtr input)
    {
        IntPtr* ptr = stackalloc IntPtr[1];
        *ptr = input;
        byte[] output = new byte[sizeof(IntPtr)];
        Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)ptr, output, 0, sizeof(IntPtr));
        return output;
    }
```

Please note that you will need to add the `unsafe` keyword and use the [unsafe-compiler-option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/unsafe-compiler-option).
you need the option to enable the use of pointers, you can activate it like this in Visual Studio:

1. right click your project
2. select "Properties"
3. select "Build" in the project-properties window
4. under "General" check "Allow unsafe code"

And if you want to convert them back, this should work:

```
    public unsafe static IntPtr ArrayToIntPtr(byte[] input)
    {
        IntPtr* ptr = stackalloc IntPtr[1];
        Marshal.Copy(input, 0, (IntPtr) ptr, sizeof(IntPtr));
        return *ptr;
    }
```

Example:

```
    public unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var v1 = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        var r1 = ArrayToIntPtr(v1);
        Console.WriteLine(r1);
        var r2 = IntPtrToArray(r1);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', r2));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Outputs:

```
578437695752307201
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

Please also note that the size of `IntPtr` is platform specific, so you'll need to supply a correctly sized `byte[]`, as you can see in my code you can get the correct size with `sizeof(IntPtr)`

**UPDATE**:
Sorry, I just figured out this might do the same, without the need of pointers and since there are only 32 and 64 bit, it should also run on all machines:

```
    public unsafe static byte[] IntPtrToArray2(IntPtr input)
    {
        return sizeof(IntPtr) == 4 ? BitConverter.GetBytes((int)input) : BitConverter.GetBytes((long)input);
    }
    public unsafe static IntPtr ArrayToIntPtr2(byte[] input)
    {
        return (IntPtr)(sizeof(IntPtr) == 4 ? BitConverter.ToInt32(input) : BitConverter.ToInt32(input));
    }
```

Comment: I just noticed i made it the wrong way around... wait a moment :D

Comment: how its help me to convert byte array to intptr?

Comment: hi, i hope it's more obvious now